# PSQL, adding a "step increasing" column

Tags: sql, postgresql

have this values in a table column `select a from tab`:

| a |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 15 |
| 16 |
| 18 |

Using a variable=3, how can create column `b` starting with min(a) and with the following values:

| a | b |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 4 |
| 5 | 4 |
| 6 | 4 |
| 7 | 7 |
| 15 | 15 |
| 17 | 15 |
| 18 | 18 |

something like: for each `a` (ordered) maintain the value at most for 3, otherwise reset.

Thanks,
AAWNSD

Comment: Can you explain why b=15 for a=15, b=15 for a=17 and b=18 for a=18?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want window functions and groups of three based on arithmetic on `a`:

```
select a,
       min(a) over (partition by ceiling(a / 3.0)) as b
from tab;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=8c3a76db98b4ebc11d182c403743c128) is a db<>fiddle.

Hmmm . . . I realize that the above returns "16" for the last row rather than 18.  My above interpretation may not be correct.  You may be saying that you want groups -- once they start -- to never exceed the group starting value plus 2.

If so, one approach is a recursive CTE:

```
with recursive tt as (
      select a, row_number() over (order by a) as seqnum
      from tab
     ),
     cte as (
      select a, seqnum, a as grp
      from tt
      where seqnum = 1
      union all
      select tt.a, tt.seqnum,
             (case when tt.a <= grp + 2 then grp else tt.a end)
      from cte join
           tt
           on tt.seqnum = cte.seqnum + 1
     )
select *
from cte;
```

Comment: this is exactly the need. Will need some hours to understand how it works! :| Thanks so much.